# Sync Framework questions

Tags: c#, sql, synchronization, sql-server-express, microsoft-sync-framework

Okay so I have to sync data between two SQL Server Express instances and after a research I stopped at Sync Framework which I think can do the job.. but since I am pushed by time and I don't have much time to do a complete research I need to ask few questions before continuing..

Basically I will have a server database which will be cleaned once every two months and I need to have a mirror database that will contain all the records.

1. Does sync synchronize the records only in the destination table or it also changes the server table if there is deleted records in it?
2. Can I sync two SQL Server Express instances? Because I am reading the documentation and it only has SQL Server and SQL Server Express sync documentation..
3. Do I need to create the mirror table or sync will create it for me?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can specify the sync direction, upload, download, upload and download, download and upload, its all up to you.
2. Yes, you can, the same SqlSyncProvider will work with SQL Express, SQL Server, Local DB and Azure SQL Database
3. When you provision, you will have to define the tables that needs to be sync (table, columns, etc...). you will then provision the sync, when you provision, if the tables dont exist, it will create it for you.

Answer (score -2):

1. Sync framework is designed to work to synchronize databases, that means two way, and it includes some concept of conflict resolution. One way synchronization is called Mirroring.
2. No you can't. Sync Framework is an enterprise level solution. You
   need to pay for it. With a SQL Server licence. Don't bother looking
   elsewhere, a SQL Server license is actually pretty cheap compared to
   the alternatives.
3. Do not know the answer.

Comment: Sync Framework is an SDK, its free and you don't pay for it. And no, its not limited to two-way sync, its up to you how you setup the sync direction.

Comment: @JuneT I would love to know how you got around the issues with triggers populating the metadata.

Comment: what do you mean get around with it? it needs the metadata to track changes.

Comment: @JuneT i mean SQL Express doesn't support the triggers needed to provide the metadata that Sync needs to Sync

Comment: who says SQL Express doesn't support triggers? SQL Express has triggers. or are you confusing it with SQL Compact?